# Why tour example question is still about unicorns?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center

This site seems to be old enough and have enough good questions. Why is example question in the [Tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) still about unicorns (its standard example question)? Some question should be chosen to be Example Question.

Comment: I thought we had already such a question.

Comment: [No](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=How+to+prevent+unicorns+from+eating+daisies), and it is @bad.

Comment: You did, @badp - [this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68156/do-blizzards-from-multiple-wizards-stack). It became ineligible; near as I can tell, that happened when the one answer with a comment got downvoted below 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tentatively picked [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/103728/how-do-i-reset-my-manor-so-i-can-rebuild-it-with-different-options) from the list of eligible questions. Other mods can go [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/admin/about/choose-question) and pick a better one.